# Selectores en css

Tags: html, css

Bueno mi duda con respecto a los selectores en css me tiene un poco frustrado porque no lo entiendo .parrafo.parrafo-1 que funcion tiene alguien me lo puede explicar o dejar algo en claro ?

- ¿porqué agregan esa combinación de selectores asi?
- ¿no es mejor usar **`.parrafo-1`** y asi solo se le agrega la clase ?

Aqui esta el enlace :https://codepen.io/manueldavid23/pen/yLOVNWx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te comento:

- Un elemento (*etiqueta HTML*) puede tener mas de una clase declarada (*esto dependerá de la [arquitectura aplicada](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/) y de las necesidades de cada desarrollo*)
- En tu ejercicio cada nodo **`p`** tiene 2 clases

  - Una genérica llamada: **`parrafo`** misma que cuando uses para construir tu(s) regla(s) CSS y afectará de manera inicial a todos los que las compartan
  - Una específica llamada: **`parrafo-#`** **la cual de hecho no me hace sentido al menos con el escenario planteado pues no existen otros párrafos que la compartan y deberían en [todo caso ser `ids`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) que son identificadores únicos para cada nodo**

Con respecto a tu regla CSS, lo que estas usando es un [selector de clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Introducci%C3%B3n/Selectors) el cual perfectamente puede quedar simplemente como:

```
.parrafo-1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: deepskyblue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

¿Por qué?

Bueno **al momento tu ejercicio no tiene otros párrafos** que compartan esta nomenclatura: **`.parrafo .parrafo-1`** entonces no es necesario ser tan específico.

¿Entonces por qué o para qué un selector del tipo que esta en el código?, bueno imagina un escenario como este:

```
<section class="listado">
  <p class="listado-parrafos parrafo1">Párrafo 1</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafos parrafo2">Párrafo 2</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafos parrafo3">Párrafo 3</p>
</section>

<section class="listado">
  <p class="listado-parrafo parrafo1">Párrafo 4</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafo parrafo2">Párrafo 5</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafo parrafo3">Párrafo 6</p>
</section>
```

El cual quiero aplicar estilos solamente a los que tienen la clase **`parrafo-1`**, del primer trio de párrafos entonces si hago esto:

```html
<style>
  .parrafo1 {
    color: crimson;
  }
</style>
<section class="listado">
  <p class="listado-parrafos parrafo1">Párrafo 1</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafos parrafo2">Párrafo 2</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafos parrafo3">Párrafo 3</p>
</section>

<section class="listado">
  <p class="listado-parrafo parrafo1">Párrafo 4</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafo parrafo2">Párrafo 5</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafo parrafo3">Párrafo 6</p>
</section>
```

Si cambia el color del párrafo, el problema es que lo hace con los párrafos 1 y 4 y yo deseo que se aplique al primero; entonces el selector debería ser así:

```html
<style>
  .listado-parrafos.parrafo1 {
    color: crimson;
  }
</style>
<section class="listado">
  <p class="listado-parrafos parrafo1">Párrafo 1</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafos parrafo2">Párrafo 2</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafos parrafo3">Párrafo 3</p>
</section>

<section class="listado">
  <p class="listado-parrafo parrafo1">Párrafo 4</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafo parrafo2">Párrafo 5</p>
  <p class="listado-parrafo parrafo3">Párrafo 6</p>
</section>
```

Conclusión:

- ¿Es estrictamente necesario un selector como este?

No y puede quedar como te propongo pero solamente bajo una estructura HTML como la que muestras

- ¿es incorrecta la forma en que se declaró el selector?

No, de hecho lo que logras es un nivel de [específicidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad) mayor  y que seguramente será de mayor funcionalidad en una estructura mas compleja.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes parte de la razón, si el css se escribiera a puño y letra.
Pero algunas veces esto aparece por el uso de compiladores de css con lenguajes como less sass o scss:

y el único objetivo de que el selector css tenga dos clases concatenadas:
es para que solo funcione sobre elementos que tengan esas dos clases.

### Ejemplo:

```css
* {
    color: green;
}

.foo.bar {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Hello Foo</div>       <!-- No seleccionado, texto verde [1] -->
<div class="foo bar">Hello World</div> <!-- si seleccionado, texto rojo [2] -->
<div class="bar">Hello Bar</div>       <!-- No seleccionado, texto verde [3] -->
```

### [Un post en inglés con datos de referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772305/4717133)